# What is the rule in the conjunction of sentences that are using present perfect?

Tags: sentence-construction, present-perfect, auxiliary-verbs

I'm using **conjunction** between two phrases, **both** of them are using the **present perfect** tense.

#### My question is:

- should I repeat the auxiliary verb have/has or I should use it only the first time? and what is the grammatical rule here?

> "Something **has done** the first thing, and **made** the second thing"

or

> "Something **has done** the first thing, and **has made** the second thing"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to repeat it if you have a parallel structure.

- He has cleaned the room and swept the porch.
- He has done his homework and picked up the clothes in his room.
- She has eaten the haddock but not touched the potatoes.

There is no need to repeat the auxiliary in a parallel structure.

Non-parallel structure:

- He *has cleaned* his room but *did not wash* his clothes.